# Python - Reading YAML file with escape characters and escape them

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, yaml

I have a yaml file with `Latex`-strings in its entries, in particular with many un-escaped escape signs `\`. The file could look like that

```yaml
content: 
    - "explanation"   : "\text{Explanation 1} "
      "formula"       : "\exp({{a}}^2)  =  {{d}}^2  -  {{b}}^2"
    - "explanation"   : "\text{Explanation 2}"
      "formula"       : "{{b}}^2         = {{d}}^2      -  \exp({{a}}^2) "
```

The desired output form (in python) looks like that:

```py
config = {
            "content" : [
            {"explanation" : "\\text{Now} ",
              "formula"    : "\\exp({{a}}^2)  =  {{d}}^2  -  {{b}}^2"},
            {"explanation" : "\\text{With}",
              "formula"    : "{{a}}^2        = {{d}}^2 + 3     ++  {{b}}^2"}
                    ]
         }
```

where the `\` have been escaped, but not the "{" and "}" as you would have when using `re.escape(string)`.

```py
path = "config.yml"
with open(path, "r",encoding = 'latin1') as stream: 
    config1 = yaml.safe_load(stream)

with open(path, "r",encoding = 'utf-8') as stream: 
    config2 = yaml.safe_load(stream)

# Codecs
import codecs
with codecs.open(path, "r",encoding='unicode_escape') as stream:
    config3 = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    
with codecs.open(path, "r",encoding='latin1') as stream:
    config4 = yaml.safe_load(stream)

with codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as stream:
    config5 = yaml.safe_load(stream)

# 
with open(path, "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as stream:
    stream = stream.read() 
    config6 = yaml.safe_load(stream)

with open(path, "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as stream:
    config7 = yaml.load(stream,Loader = Loader)
```

None of these solutions seems to work, e.g. the "unicode-escape" option still reads in
`\x1bxp({{a}}^2)` instead of `\exp({{a}}^2)`.

What can I do? (The dictionary entries are later given to a Latex-Parser but I can't escape all the `\` signs by hand.).

Comment: What generated the YAML file? `\n`, `\e` and `\t` are all special characters when enclosed in double quotes in YAML. You need to rewrite whatever generates the YAML file and make it not enclose those values in double quotes. These characters are otherwise going to be interpreted as special characters unless you write your own non-YAML parser.

Comment: Is there no way around this? Isn't there no function reading in the yaml string from file and escaping the \ before the yaml parser reads it?

Comment: And is there any file format, that reads in latex strings and escapes their \ signs?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Instead *"The file could look like that"* show output from `cat config.yml` (or `type config.yml`).

Answer (score 1):

`\n`, `\e` and `\t` are all special characters when double-quoted in YAML, and if you're going treat them literally you're basically asking the YAML parser to blindly treat double-quoted text as plain text, which means that you're going to have to write your own non-conforming YAML parser.

Instead of writing a parser from the ground up, however, an easier approach would be to customize an existing YAML parser by monkey-patching the method that scans double-quoted texts and making it the same as the method that scans plain texts. In case of PyYAML, that can be done with a simple override:

```
yaml.scanner.Scanner.fetch_double = yaml.scanner.Scanner.fetch_plain
```

If you want to avoid affecting other parts of the code that may parse YAML normally, you can use `unittest.mock.patch` as a context manager to patch the `fetch_double` method temporarily just for the loader call:

```
import yaml
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch('yaml.scanner.Scanner.fetch_double', yaml.scanner.Scanner.fetch_plain):
    with open('config.yml') as stream:
        config = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

With your sample input, `config` would become:

```
{
    'content': [
        {'"explanation"': '"\\text{Explanation 1} "',
         '"formula"': '"\\exp({{a}}^2)  =  {{d}}^2  -  {{b}}^2"'},
        {'"explanation"': '"\\text{Explanation 2}"',
         '"formula"': '"{{b}}^2         = {{d}}^2      -  \\exp({{a}}^2) "'}
    ]
}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/WaryDirectWorkplaces

Note that this approach comes with the obvious consequence that you lose all the capabilities of double quotes within the same call. If the configuration file has other double-quoted texts that need proper escaping, this will not parse them correctly. But if the configuration file has only the kind of input you posted in your question, it will help parse it in the way you prefer without having to modify the code that generates such an (improper) YAML file (since presumably you're asking this question because you don't have the authorization to modify the code that generates the YAML file).